# Unable to capture datetime value from jquery datetime picker in asp.net page (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datetime

Pretty simple, here is the js:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txt_Date]").datepicker({      
        });

    });

    //Set the default date today
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        $("#txt_Date").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
    });

</script>
```

Here is the control on the page.  The page has a master page and in the content area the control is nested in an asp:Table, asp:TableRow, asp:TableCell structure.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Date" columns="30" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" name="RequestDate"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the code behind where I attempt to capture the value on a submit_click:

```
Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["txt_Date"]);
```

I have also tried:

```
Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["RequestDate"]);
```

Every attempt has returned 01/01/0001 as the date which I am guessing is just the default when it reads a NULL value from the control  I am sure this is probably simple but I must be missing it.

Comment: Have you tried `txt_Date.Value`?

Comment: I have notice one thing you are adding datepicker to single control two times , you dont need this code 
$(function () {
        $("[id$=txt_Date]").datepicker({      
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use:

```
Date = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_Date.Text);
```

I have noticed one more thing which is not required

```
 $(function () {
        $("[id$=txt_Date]").datepicker({      
        });    
    });
```

As you are already writing initialization & assignment in document ready event.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was pretty simple, it is just a lack of experience at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Because ReadOnly is set to true, `Request.Form` will not contain your data. You can either access the Text property as suggested in another answer, or you can remove the ReadOnly attribute, which I think is the better option. It's generally best to handle user input through validation instead of attempting to restrict said input (I remember the days when everyone thought it was a good idea to disable the back button).